# WCF File has 3 different .cs files(Service, Contract, Interface) for a WebForm of UI Solution, Please explain

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, user-interface, iis

**I am a beginner so Sorry in advance If I'm asking anything stupid.** 
I have seen that in a project in ASP.Net there is an UI file in solution and a WCF file for that UI file. A Particular Web form (aspx Page) of UI has 3 .cs file in WCF(Service, Contract, Interface). So does that mean every Web form of UI will have 3 same kind of .cs file for that?